# Fetch Images from server into gridview in flutter

Tags: api, gridview, flutter

I have tried but couldn't get my head around with the docs.

I want to load images from server and load them into a gridview. The server sends 10 images at a time. When the gridview has been scrolled to bottom, it should send request for next 10 items. When the user clicks on a particular photo it would be opened in another widget with extra details. Performance is a major concern.

I am not asking for code. I just want the exact direction. It shall help establish the community for flutter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I accomplished this when building an [Instagram clone](https://github.com/mdanics/fluttergram) with Flutter. If you are familiar with Instagram, a profile page has a grid of images which are the user's post. You can then click on the image and it will open the image into a 'fullscreen' widget where you have the ability do to other actions (like commenting and liking).

If you are interested in the code, you can check it out [here](https://github.com/mdanics/fluttergram/blob/master/lib/profile_page.dart). The function `buildUserPosts` is where the grid is created.

Comment: I really appreciate your hard work... As a suggestion, you should do a youtube series. This shall be a nice lesson for the community

Comment: Glad I could help. A youtube series has been requested a few times, but I don't have a lot of time on my hands anymore. When I free up it's on my todo list.

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer to the question in the below link will help. In your case just change it to `GridView` instead of `ListView`.

[view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49326542/adding-a-future-api-call-to-json-data-as-infinate-scroll-flutter-gallery-examp/51542519#51542519)

Answer (score 0):

[flutter_image_gallery_example][1]
[https://github.com/andrea7887/flutter_image_gallery_example/blob/master/lib/main.dart][1]

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: GalleryDemo(),
    );
  }
}

class GalleryDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  GalleryDemo({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Image Gallery Example"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
            future: fetchGalleryData(),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return GridView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                        crossAxisCount: 2),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                          child: Container(
                              decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                                  image: new DecorationImage(
                                      image: new NetworkImage(
                                          snapshot.data[index]),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover))));
                    });
              }
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            },
          ),
        ));
  }
}

Future<List<String>> fetchGalleryData() async {
  try {
    final response = await http
        .get(
            'https://kaleidosblog.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/flutter_gallery/data.json')
        .timeout(Duration(seconds: 5));

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return compute(parseGalleryData, response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load');
    }
  } on SocketException catch (e) {
    throw Exception('Failed to load');
  }
}

List<String> parseGalleryData(String responseBody) {
  final parsed = List<String>.from(json.decode(responseBody));
  return parsed;
}
```